# My Html.ActionLink doesn't work using ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.actionlink

I just basically need to redirect from one page (Page 1) to another page (Page 2).

Here's my view - Page 1:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reviews", "MyActionStuff", "MyController",  null, null)
```

Here's my controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyActionStuff() 
    {
        return View(View("~/Views/Shared/MyViewFolder/MyView.cshtml", myModel);)
    }
}
```

My destination view - Page 2 - `MyView.cshtml`:

```
@model My.Models.SomeModel

// display model attributes.
```

I'm not really sure why as simple as having a link using `@Html.ActionLink` doesn't work.

I did try to debug and it appears it's not even invoking my controller - it just goes to 404 error.

I tried to use `@Url.Action` but I got the same thing.

I followed / patterned my `Html.Action` link from here but still the same issue.

Comment: The controller code has a syntax error and won't compile like that.  Surely the compiler is telling you this...

Comment: the controller code that I pasted is just a snippet code. there's a lot more and I dont want to give the whole code. I was just hoping that giving that snippet of code will give the context of of the issue.

Comment: Well, that snippet code has a syntax error and won't compile.  The only way that controller will be able to respond to browser requests *at all* is if it's valid and compile-able code.  What you have here is essentially a typo.

Comment: well I tell you, my code compiles, its just i didn't want post the whole code here. maybe you can bypass this and look somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

the culprit is the naming convention, I had to remove the 'controller' suffix when calling it >: